# Strange jitter on menus in chrome

Tags: navigation

In chrome, when I put my mouse over any of the menu items below, the menu starts jumping up and down, and I cannot choose any item.  Has anyone else seen this?  It happens in Chrome, but not FireFox nor IE.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest public release version of Chrome? Also are you using any plugins that use JavaScript? IE FireBug. Try Disabling all plugins and making sure the Chrome version is the latest public release.

Comment: You modified may have done some css styling wrong, and the hovered menu is bigger than the css styles. Therefore causing a loop, on and off the menu.

Comment: @Mike - I did not modify any styling

Comment: @Hugh - yes, the latest chrome.  I do have plugins, and the IE tab plugin makes this work properly without jitter.

Comment: Try just disabling the plugins, to see if it works, because on the exact same menu an out of the box install works perfectly. Being Chrome you can also just run the JavaScript profiler to debug the situation and find out what's going on.

Comment: Daniel, since based on the answer this could be a bug in Chrome, could you add your browser version number to the question? That could help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a newly discovered issue, I get it too.
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/hXdsw2pwgD0

as a reference, here is a quote from the discussion:

> Confirmed this issue - win 7 x64 sp1 
>   Site impacted is an internal SharePoint site (sections impacted appear to
>   be document libraries (some not all). 
>   SharePoint platform is 2007 Enterprise
>
> Bug identified in Chrome Stable - 23.0.1271.84 
>   Replicated in Chrome Dev - 25.0.1323.1 dev-m
>
> Bug does not appear in Canary - 25.0.1324.0 canary.
>
> Bug also does not appear in older version of chrome stable - 22.0.1229.94